# const reference of std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, reference

For one of my functions, cppcheck returns:
**Parameter 'neighbors' is passed by value. It could be passed as a (const) reference which is usually faster and recommended in C++.**

I get that it doesn't make sense to allocate the vector twice when a reference could be passed, but I really don't know how to do this.... 
I've tried a lot of similiar answers here, but I couldn't find one that really fits my problem.

**Class vectorMatrix**

This function gets all neighbors and stores them in an

```
std::vector<Cell*> vectorMatrix::getCellNeighbors(int x, int y) {
    std::vector<Cell*> neighbors;
    return neighbors;
}
```

This function passes the neighbors for each cell to the cell (which stores them for quick access... they are needed every click)

```
  void vectorMatrix::initCells()
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < _rows; x++)
    {
      for (int y = 0; y < _columns; y++)
      {
        _cellMatrix[x][y]->setNeighbors(getCellNeighbors(x, y));
      }
    }
  }
```

**Class Cell**

HXX

```
std::vector<Cell*> _neighbors;
```

CXX

```
void Cell::setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors)
{
  _neighbors = neighbors;
}
```

.) How do i pass the vector correctly as a (const?) reference.
.) Is this code efficient? Does it make sense to store references to all neighbors inside each cell? (map size can be up to 256x256 and each tile is an object)

The full code can be found here:
https://github.com/JimmySnails/IsometricEngine

Comment: `const_cast<const std::vector<Cell*>>` : is this what you want?

Comment: I‘d prefer a detailed answer, that‘s not enough for me to understand how to pass const refs...

Comment: I was asking for a clarification. Anyway do you want a constant vector or a vector of constant Cells? Or a constant Vector of constant Cells?

Comment: How does your function ccpCheck look? Your getCellNeighbors is not "proper" as it just returns a local variable, that is just copied, perhaps there is other code in there, not shown?.

Comment: oh, sry. the vector itself should be a const reference according to cppcheck. Now that i think of it, the Cell* inside COULD be constant as they won't change. Would this help with performance or just for "safety"

Comment: @TotteKarlsson cppcheck is a static code analysis tool, not a function!

Comment: Baseline questions: Do you know what `const` does and a reference is? I need to know in order to tailor an answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have thought about memory ownership and lifetimes. When you call setNeighbours you are copying the vector. Is this really what you want (or do you want to move it)? Who is owning memory for neighbors? what about the pointers that you store in the vector?  If you want to ignore this, you can always pass a pointer or a reference to a vector

Comment: @user4581301 yes i do but i don't know how to implement it

Comment: @steve no, i haven't yet. but the pointers to cell class and the vectors themselves are needed throughout the whole game lifecycle. i _think_ it doesn't matter who owns the memory so a move should be ok too, but please correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

I believe this code:

```
void Cell::setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors)
{
  _neighbors = neighbors;
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
void Cell::setNeighbors(const std::vector<Cell*> &neighbors)
{
  _neighbors = neighbors;
}
```

Comment: It seems your checker is a bit out of date.  Your "fix" saves one move which costs almost nothing, but still requires a copy.  In C++11 and later, the *much* faster approach is `void Cell::setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors)
{
  _neighbors = std::move(neighbors);
}` which will require *zero* copies (and two moves).  Even in C++03, it would have been just as good to write `void Cell::setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors)
{
  _neighbors.swap(neighbors);
}`

Comment: Thank you both. std::move(neighbors) works and even sped up my code by ~50 ms for 128 x 128 tiles! Is std::move enough or is there anything else i should consider?

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt for your feedback. Yes it seems it is "a bit out of date". For setters, we should probably start recommending `std::move()` instead. However I assume that const reference is better in many other cases. if you just want to loop through the elements and do stuff for instance then moving/copying is not a good idea.

Comment: For information, I added http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8590 so Cppcheck should make better recommendations in the future..